# TextInput with value doesn't change value

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

In my react-native app i have an API that I'm retrieving data from, and I'm setting the data inside my input values, user should be able to edit those inputs and update, but when i try to type in the input it won't type anything and the value stays as it is, here is the TextInput code:

```
<TextInput
   placeholder= Email
   value={this.state.info.email}
   onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I don't think email is the only prop of your `state.info` I recommend you to use `setState()` properly, in order to modify just that field. According to immutability and ES6, something like:

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="Email"
  value={this.state.info.email}
  onChangeText={text =>
    this.setState(state => ({
      info: {
        ...state.info,
        email: text
    }))
  }
/>;
```

Read more about handling `TextInput` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input)

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same issue until I changed the `value` prop to `defaultValue` like this:

```
<TextInput
   style={styles.inputBox}
   onChangeText={title => this.setState({ title })}
   defaultValue={this.state.title}
   placeholder='Title'
/>
```

I found this info on React's documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-text-input)

Comment: defaultValue can not take number so you have to give it as string.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to declare the state and then apply that state to TextInput Value.

```
state: {
     email: ''
}
```

and to populate TextInput for first time with the API value you have to add

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({email: this.props.info.email});
}
```

and your TextInput will be like below:

```
<TextInput
   placeholder= Email
   value={this.state.email}
   onChangeText={value=> this.setState({ email: value})}/>
```

Hope this works..

Comment: `onChangeText={value=> this.setState({ email: value})}` here you will get incorrect value because event object is passed to the handler function.  The correct code is `event => this.setState({email: event.target.value})`

Answer (score 2):

I am also having the same issue until I changed the value prop to defaultValue like this:

```
<TextInput
   style={styles.inputBoxSize}
   onChangeText={title => this.setState({ title })}
   defaultValue={this.state.title}
   placeholder='Title'
/>
```

value={this.state.title} - instead of this

defaultValue={this.state.title} - use this one

Thats all. Enjoy your coding...

Answer (score 2):

***If above answere didn't work!***

**try it like this**

When you change the ***`value`*** prop to ***`defaultValue`*** you have to make it a string,

`defaultValue` does not take `number`

You can use  **`toString()`** method to convert it into string.

like shown below

```
<TextInput
   style={styles.inputBox}
   onChangeText={title => setState(title )}
   defaultValue={title.toString()}
   placeholder='Title'
/>
```

more info about this on React's documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-text-input)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your handler function. When you called setState you updated the `this.state.email` but in your text input value you used `this.state.info.email`, you also wrote the event object to the email, instead of the new value of the field (`event.target.value`). You should use something like this.

```
onChangeHandler = event => {
  const newEmail = event.target.value
  this.setState({ info: {email: newEmail})}
}

<TextInput
  placeholder= Email
  value={this.state.info.email}
  onChangeText={this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is a good approach or not but [**Dustin Spengler**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4893747/dustin-spengler) answer worked for me without any problem. I don't have enough reputation to upvote and to comment.

```
<TextInput
style={styles.inputBox}
onChangeText={title => this.setState({ title })}
defaultValue={this.state.title}
placeholder='Title'
/>
```